# Add custom script for bokeh curdoc

Tags: javascript, python, google-analytics, bokeh

I want to add the google analytics script to a bokeh app that I serve using bokeh serve command. 
Currently, I use,

```
l = layout([[h_div], [t1_div, t2_div, t3_div], [widgets, plots, prob_grid]], sizing_mode="fixed")
curdoc().add_root(l)
curdoc().title = "Title"
session_doc = curdoc()
```

to create the page.

Here, h_div, tx_div are html markups from `bokeh.models.widgets.markups`.

Is it possible to include `<script> ... </script>`, into this page to be used with Google Analytics.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I could add this using a template file.

Ref: http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html